# How do I use WebClient to make Basic Authentication calls to IIS WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, webclient

Using a `PowerShell Cmdlet` encapsulating a `WebClient` call to a `WebAPI`, I am attempting to implement Basic Authentication.  I have tried a couple methods and settled on adding a Filter to the `WebAPI` as suggested here [WebAPI Authentication Filter](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter#Resources).

FYI: Since this is to be a file-upload tool I would prefer the data only be sent once, as the files will be up to 10MB text logs, hence I am creating the header for the first contact.

From the `PowerShell Cmdlet`:

```
private async Task<string> Run(string postBody, string Username, string Password)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = Common.DefaultMediaType;

        var credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Username + ":" + Password));
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = $"Basic {credentials}";

        string response;
        try
        {
            response = await client.UploadStringTaskAsync($"{_baseAddress}/{_uriTestConPost}", postBody);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            var webResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (webResponse == null) throw ex;

            WriteWarning("WebException: " + webResponse.StatusCode);
            return null;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Running this code as is produced a 401, and no echoes in the debugger.

Running this code with the credentials and header commented out creates two messages from Fiddler, one without authorization and another with authorization.  Both get denied with 401 **but** the debugger on the `WebAPI Controller` shows that I am only attempting to authorize the first time, the second attempt is formed correctly with the encoded authorization header but is rejected with code 401 without ever hitting the debugger.

The `ApiController` is as simple as I could make it to verify:

```
public class TestReportController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [McpBasicAuthenticationFilter]
    public async Task<string> TestConnectionPost()
    {
        dynamic message = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return "You sent " + message.ToString();
    }
}
```

At this point, I have to think the authorization problem is my `web.Config` or my IIS setup.  For IIS I have Anonymous and Basic Authorization enabled (other parts of the site need anonymous access).

Important area of the WebConfig from what I can tell:

```
<system.web>
     <authentication mode="None" />
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" executionTimeout="240000" maxRequestLength="1073741824" />
     <identity impersonate="false" />
 </system.web>
```

**What is blocking the requests that have the credentials?**

Comment: Instead of adding your own custom headers, why not use the [Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the WebClient?

Comment: Have you checked your IIS settings?  Is basic identification allowed?  I would start by accessing the api from the webserver itself if possible to see if it responds.

Comment: @mason using `.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);` causes the standard approach: sending an anonymous request which fails and is then resent using the credentials.  Since this tool will eventually be pushing large log files to the server (the biggest is theoretically 180MB) I want to avoid sending the information twice.  What I am adding is not custom headers, `HttpRequestHeader.Authorization` is a .NET provided constant value.  This is just manually doing what is automated within `WebClient`.

Comment: @HaimKatz I have enabled Anonymous and Basic Authentication.  Even with Anonymous turned off I get 401 return.  I need both because some of the website is anonymous access.  Is there something else I need to do in order to get this working?  I have read a few How To's that I am fairly certain I didn't miss any steps.  I am pretty sure you are right that it is an IIS level issue but I left work yesterday just stumped.

Comment: I use basic authentication often.  You're web config should be   <authentication mode="Windows" />.  Your directory where the web application is also needs file permissions for the user's you are authenticating.

Comment: @HaimKatz That would be Windows Authentication... not necessarily Basic.  These users have no accounts on the local machine.  This validates via a local db and uses the default security associated with the IIS App Pool account.  Windows mode is specifically for integrated intranet apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114(v=vs.71).aspx
This is how I understand IIS authentication.  I am not an authority by any means but I'll tell how I use it and how it works for me.  Basically the authentication on IIS tells the website how to handle the handshake between the client and the server, but they all use windows permissions.  (even the anonymous requires the user to be using the IIS default user account or one with permissions to access the site).
There is the ASP.NET authentication which you can use Windows or Forms. When I want to validate a user from a database and not from active directory, I use anonymous authentication in IIS and forms authentication in my web.config. The credentials are passed in either through a logon form or the query string. 
I have been using ASP.Net identity lately.  It does almost all the plumbing and is very easy to set up.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes/
There of course is a lot of stuff out there on this.

Comment: I will have to take a look at this later as I have been pulled off project a bit. I use a lot of intranet authorization with identities, the rest is a little different to me and I am going to have to work into this a bit.  If I can figure this out from your data I will definitely mark it as answered, but that may be a couple weeks.